# Content Not Posting to Database but Getting Sucess Message

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I seem to be having an issue with inserting records into a database. I am getting the success message but when I review the information in the database all the fields are plank. Is there an error in my syntax I am missing?

```
if(isset($_POST['client'])) {
    $id = (int)$id;
    $client_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['client']);
    $contact_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contact']);
    $title_to_insert =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
    $assigned_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['assigned']);
    $start_date_to_insert = stripslashes($_POST['start_date']);
    $end_date_to_insert = stripslashes($_POST['end_date']);
    $status_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']);
    $amount_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['amount']);
    $costs_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['costs']);
    $costs2_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['costs2']);
    $costs_item_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['costs_item']);
    $costs_item2_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['costs_item2']);
    $notes_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['area']);
    $feeA_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['feeA']);
    $feeB_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['feeB']);
    $feeC_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['feeC']);
    $feeD_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['feeD']);
    $feeE_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['feeE']);
    $feeF_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['feeF']);
    $feeG_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['feeG']);
    $feeH_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['feeH']);
    $feeI_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['feeI']);
    $feeK_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['feeK']);
    $feeL_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['feeL']);
    $feeM_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['feeM']);
    $feeN_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['feeN']);
    $contract_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contract']);
    $outofhouse_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['outofhouse']);
    $vendor_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['vendor']);
    $vendor1_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['vendor1']);
    $billed_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['billed']);
    $billing_need_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['billing_need']);
    $extended_billing_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['extended_billing']);
    $contract_value_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contract_value']);
    $retainer_value_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['retainer_value']);


    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO projects (
    id,
    client,
    contact,
    title,
    assigned,
    start_date,
    end_date,
    status,
    amount,
    costs,
    costs2,
    costs_item,
    costs_item2,
    notes,
    feeA, 
    feeB,
    feeC,
    feeD,
    feeE,
    feeF,
    feeG,
    feeH, 
    feeI, 
    feeK, 
    feeL, 
    feeM, 
    feeN, 
    contract, 
    billed, 
    billing_need, 
    extended_billing, 
    vendor, 
    vendor1, 
    outofhouse, 
    retainer_value, 
    contract_value
    )

    VALUES (
    '$id' ,
    '$client' ,
    '$contact' ,
    '$title' ,
    '$assigned' ,
    '$start_date' , 
    '$end_date' , 
    '$status' , 
    '$amount' , 
    '$costs' , 
    '$costs2' ,
    '$costs_item' ,
    '$costs_item2' , 
    '$notes' , 
    '$feeA' , 
    '$feeB' ,
    '$feeC' ,
    '$feeD' , 
    '$feeE' , 
    '$feeF' , 
    '$feeG' , 
    '$feeH' , 
    '$feeI' , 
    '$feeK' , 
    '$feeL' , 
    '$feeM' , 
    '$feeN' , 
    '$contract' , 
    '$billed' , 
    '$billing_need' , 
    '$extended_billing' , 
    '$vendor' ,
    '$vendor1' ,
    '$outofhouse' , 
    '$retainer_value' , 
    '$contract_value' );");


    if($query) {
        $message = "Success your Project has been added!";

    }else{
        $message = "An error occurred while adding this Project";
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I will look into PDO and MySQLi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @hakre mentioned, the sql looks fine, but you could use

```
mysql_query("INSERT...") or die(mysql_error());
```

to check that there aren't any problems such as missing or misnamed fields in your database

Comment: It seems that if I remove the additional masking of "_to_insert" on the variables everything works fine? What implementations would I be looking that if I just removed those?

Comment: @pixelJockey: now that you said it, the error seems obvious - the variables you used in the SQL query are not the same ones you stored `mysql_real_escape_string` values into! (A competent IDE would have highlighted the SQL query string as containing uninitialized variables.)

Comment: @pixelJockey as DCoder has said, now that the error has been revealed it seems obvious. All you should need to do now is make sure the variable names match, so just remove "_to_insert" from all variable names and the code should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL looks fine [as far as the context allows to say so] (that is why you see a new row each time when you run this) however, I suggest you die before running the query and output it first. So you can take a look what you've might be doing wrong.

```
$sql   = "INSERT INTO projects (...";
var_dump($sql);
die();

$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's always worked for me in similar cases is echoing the sql query and copy & paste it directly into the DB and THEN see if there's any problem. Also, it may be worthy checking the `mysql_affected_rows($sql)`.